# how do I know when a user has selected an auto complete suggestion in a text box?

Tags: winforms

Using Winforms 2.0

I have a text box with a custom autocompletecollection source and the mode is *suggest*.

How do I know when the user selects a suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply compare strings (inputed with avaliable). Or use combo box for extended control of inputed values.

Comment: thre are about 5000 strings comparing with each of them every time seems silly
 I just want an event that would fire when he selects one of the drop down suggestions and hits enter

Answer (score 0):

i couldn't get you properly.

if you gave suggest Mode.i will explain using Dropdown 
if user start entering value in drop down automatically the suggested value populate.if he is entering continuously that new value added to that drop down.

Now let's consider about Text box
                when ever you enter text box value you need to save a local file or otherwise then only you can able to support suggest mode.with out having source for that text box how you can know what are the values present  that text box.

Explain briefly please

thanks,

KRG

Comment: it only automaticaly populates if you set the value to suggest append not just suggest